# Access to phpmyadmin is not possible now due to redirection of virtualhosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a server with two subdomains, so I set up redirection for both of my subdomains specially because I want to force that the two subdomains are accessed only by https instead of http. My ideal scenario would be that I have those redirection untouched and be able to access phpMyAdmin locally (for security reasons obviously) but the problem now is that when I type the following in my browser: 
127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin or localhost/phpmyadmin it takes me to https://example1.com/webservice/myrestfile-REST.php?appconfig=example

Is there any way to solve this problem?

This is the configuration that I currently have with the redirection:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName example1.com
 ServerAlias API.com
 ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/html/requests.log combined
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html

 RewriteEngine On

 LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^ https://example1.com/webservice/myrestfile-REST.php?appconfig=example [R,L]


Redirect permanent / https://example1.com

#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webservice/myrestfile-REST.php?appconfig=example [QSA,L]


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

 RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webservice/myrestfile-REST.php?appconfig=example [QSA,L] 
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/40d5d69ae6a53.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/sitekey.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have apache set to listen on any ip `<VirtualHost *:80>` which would include the loopback address `127.0.0.1`. See if you can just use the condition to ignore those.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webservice/myrestfile-REST.php?appconfig=example [QSA,L]
```

See how that works and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response I actually have 2 <VirtualHost *:80>  and 2 <VirtualHost *:443>. the first two *:80 are for each subdomain that I have and the two 443 are to force them to be https. I pasted those lines but first it gave me an error: `RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression '^127\\.0\\.0.\\1' ` ThenI changed that line to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^127.0.0.1 [OR] ` but still same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I had one slash in the wrong place. Try the updated rule. And you can use the same rule for 443 vhost as well.

Comment: I also was wondering why I should use this RewriteRule:  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webservice/myrestfile-REST.php?appconfig=example [QSA,L] `  instead of the one I originally had `RewriteRule ^ https://example1.com/webservice/myrestfile-REST.php?appconfig=example [R,L]`

Comment: the slash after the 1 here `!^127\.0\.0\.1`. I already fixed the answer. Also I just used the rule you had in your 443 vhost. You don't really need `(.*)` because you're not using the capture in your rewrite so you can just use ^.

Comment: :( it seems like still didn't work. When I do 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin it redirects to https://example1.com/webservice/myrestfile-REST.php?appconfig=example

Comment: The rules do work as I have them to prevent it from redirecting. Did you clear your cache or try in another browser? Make sure the conditions are the same.

Comment: I cleared the cache and tried in other browser and still didn't work. In fact I delected the virtualhosts to see if it was getting the configuration and then I tried to look for localhost or 127.0.0.1 and phpmyadmin and now it was working

Comment: You have to make sure you restart apache everytime you make a change to the vhost. Maybe you were forgetting to do that. But the rules should work as posted it. So that may have been why it wasn't working.

Comment: sorry I didn't make myself clear, It's still not working as I want it to work. I meant localhost and 127.0.0.1 is working only if I delete all the vhost lines inside of the apache configuration file. But if I add it back it just redirects me to the php file.